# How to add a git initialized sub directory to staging area and then commit?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I type:

```
git add folder_name
```

git bash output the message:

> **fatal: pathspec 'folder_name/' did not match any files**

My intention is to add the git initialized sub-directory to the staging area and then commit.

Comment: Is that folder empty?  If so, you can't add an empty folder to the stage, you'll need to have some content in there already.

Answer (score 1):

Empty directories are not considered as content and hence cannot be committed.

If you still wish to add it anyway, just add a `.gitignore` file in that folder and stage this file for the next commit.